# Probability of two people meeting in a given 5 x 5 square grid such that they start from bottom left and top right at same time and with same pace

Tags: combinatorics

Answer should be
Total no of cases in which they are meeting/ Total no of cases

Total no of cases are : [(5+5)!/5!5!]^2 which is equal to [10!/5!5!]^2
Now for the case of meeting: let number of horizontal steps moved by A is h and
no of vertical steps moved by A is v
So, no of horizontal steps moved by B is 5-h and vertical steps moved by B is 5-v
Also h+v should be equal to 5 as h+v should be equal to 10-(h+v).i.e total steps
moved by A and B should be equal as they are moving with same pace

So,numerator should be equal to [summation([(h+v)!]^4/[h!]^4[v!]^4)]  from h=0 to h=5
On calculating answer should be 253/756
Why people are calculating answers as 63/256?

---

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Can they move in any direction they want (up, down, left right)? When do they stop moving?

Comment: @Jens A is allowed to move in up right direction whereas B is allowed to move in bottom left direction...they have to stop when they reach the diagonally oppposite ends

Comment: @AnuragKedia: You should edit that information into your question. Without it, it is impossible to answer your question, and not everybody will read the comments.

Comment: @TonyK I have edited the question and please can you calculate answer for me ....my answer is 253/756...whereas many sites are giving answer as 63/256

Comment: "I have edited the question...": No you haven't!

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

Draw a figure! At which lattice points can A, resp., B be after $1$, $2$, $\ldots$ steps? At which lattice points can they meet, if at all? For each of these points, what is the probability that both get there (necessarily at the same time)?

Some more: A hits the diagonal $j+k=5$ in exactly one point, after exactly five steps. So far he had $2^5=32$ choices.  The probability $p_j$ that he thereby arrives at the exact point $(j,5-j)$ is given by $$p_j={1\over 2^5}{5\choose j}\qquad(0\leq j\leq5)\ .$$
(Think of Pascal's triangle!). – Same thing for B. The probability $p$ that they hit the same point on this diagonal therefore is
$$p=\sum_{j=0}^5 p_j^2=\ldots={63\over256}\ .$$

Comment: Can u please calculate the answer and verify it with my answer which turns out to be 253/756.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. The book answer ${63\over256}$ is correct.

Comment: They are taking total cases as  pow(2,10) which is totally irrelevant whereas total cases should be  square of (10!/5!5!) Which is 252 x 252

Comment: A has $2^5$ ways of reaching the top left-bottom right diagonal and B has $2^5$ ways also. So the total number of cases is $2^{10}$. You are counting the square of total number of paths from one corner to the opposite corner, but if they miss on the diagonal they can never meet, so their routes after crossing the diagonal are irrelevant.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter  I am asking in that case when both persons A and B are completing their journeys and they had meet after their fifth step and continued to complete their journey........and your answer 63/256 will come in that case if you count only 5 steps for each and probability of meeting them is given out to find

Comment: Maybe they went to a bar after they met, and did not finish their ways as they had planned. – This is my last word on this matter.